# Why is "da" used in this question?

Tags: prepositions

The following sentence comes from Duolingo:

> Kiom **da** gekuzoj vi havas?

translates to:

> How many cousins do you have?

*da* means *of*. Why is it used in this question? Is the question grammatically correct without it? It is not like I have a list of cousins (*listo da gekuzoj*).

Comment: This is an example of the genitive case. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genitive_case.

Comment: shouldn't "how much of cousins" be 'how many...'?

Comment: No, it is not, at least not in the core sence "possession" of the genetive. _da_ is a quantitative expression.

Comment: "Kiom da" means how much/many or what quantity

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*Da* and *de* both mean "of". *Da* is strictly used for quantities and measures. *De* is for possession and other uses.

Without the use of *da* here, there would be no relation between *kiom* and *gekuzoj*.

**da** 
*Prep. uzata por rilatigi du vortojn aŭ sintagmojn, el kiuj la unua esprimas mezuron (kvanton, pezon, longon, volumenon k.a.) de la dua* 
Preposition used to relate two words - the first expresses a measurement (quantity, weight, length, volume) of the second.

**Examples**:

- Sixty pages of text. 
   *60 paĝoj da teksto*
- One kilogram of tea. 
   *unu kilogramo da teo*
- A lot of paper. 
   *multe da papero*

Answer (score 10):

*Kiom* is used without *da* in questions such as *Kiom estas la duoblo de 6?*, or *Kiom estas la tempo?*. It can be translated as "how much" followed by a numerical expression (algebraic, or of time): "How much is the double of 6?", "How much is the time" (not very elegant translation!)

Cousins are not a numerical expressions, so you add *da* to turn it into one: "How much of cousins do you have?" So *kiom da* is required to make sense, as it means "How much of".

(Examples from RosxReVo iOS app)

Comment: _duolo_ is new to me

Comment: @AntonSherwood That's because it's a typo! :)

Comment: Bedaùrinde! Mi kredis havi okazon lerni novaĵon!