# Difference between 'da' and 'de'?

Tags: word-usage

I can't seem to work out the difference between *da* and *de* on Duolingo (admittedly I haven't spent long on it). Could someone give an exact distinction?

Comment: Have a look at http://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/737/why-is-da-used-in-this-question/743#743 -- that might partly answer your question.

Comment: @OliverMason Thanks that answers it. Should I delete my post (I'm new to stack exchange)?

Comment: No, I'll mark it as duplicate.

Comment: @OliverMason I do not think this is duplicate. The other question asks about the use of "da" in a particular sentence. This asks about the general distinction between "da" and "de", which is a difficult thing for many beginners. The answers there may not be extensive enough, so if someone is looking for the difference between "da" and "de", this question here is a better place for more detailes answers with more examples.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The notes in the Duolingo lesson you refer to

https://www.duolingo.com/skill/eo/Da_De

are actually very useful, they start off

> Although both *da* and *de* can be translated into English as *of*, they have different meanings:
>
> Use *da* when you're talking about quantity.
>
> Use *de* when talking about possession

with

> *taso da teo* - a cup of tea (quantity)
>
> *la patrino de la knabo* - the mother of the boy /the boy's mother

It goes on to give lots of examples and ends with the subtle case:

> When you're talking about a quantity of a specific thing or set of things, >as opposed to a type of thing, you use *de la*.
>
> *Mi bezonas 5 kilogramojn da sukero* - I need 5 kilograms of sugar.
>
> *Mi bezonas 5 kilogramojn de la sukero* - I need 5 kilograms of the sugar.

Beyond the Duolingo notes, here is an easy trick for English speakers: if you can replace *of* with *made of* or *made up of* in the sense of measure/quantity, use *da*.

> One kilogram of feathers - One kilogram made of feathers - *kilogramo DA plumoj*
>
> One cup of tea - One cup made of tea (cup is a measure unit here) - Taso DA teo*.

Note: for *made of* in the sense of material, use *el*.

> One cup made of clay - *Taso EL argilo.*

Comment: That's useful, perhaps you could edit my answer to include that?

Comment: Ok, that's done.

Comment: @Vanege This is an interesting advice, however, people should use it only for quantities and not take it as too general because when something is (physically) *made of* something, the correct preposition is "el": *seĝo el ligno* = *chair made of wood*

Comment: @LyubomirVasilev You are right, that is an important condition.

Comment: @Vanege - dankon.

Comment: Dankon. The Duolingo app doesn't have notes, I'll try the web version.