# Why did "kiom", "tiom", "iom" etc. without "da" fall out of fashion?

Tags: prepositions, language-evolution

Nowadays, when an amount tabelvorto (*"kiom"*, *"tiom"*, *"iom"*, *"ĉiom"* or *"neniom"*) is followed by the thing(s) or category to which the amount refers, there's always a *"da"* between them. (See also [Why is "da" used in this question?](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/737/why-is-da-used-in-this-question).)

This goes for countable quantities:

> Kiom **da** gekuzoj vi havas?

... as well as for uncountable ones:

> Kiom **da** akvo vi volas trinki?

As [this answer](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/a/5464/1576) to [How to mark accusative for correlatives of quantity? Kiel marki akuzativon ĉe "...iom"-aj tabelvortoj?](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/q/5456/1576) points out, this though hasn't always been the case:

> Actually the *tiom/kiom* words [used to accept the n-ending](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/kvantaj_vortoj/vortetoj.html#i-pla); Hence you could say "Kiom **laboristojn** bezonas tiom da laboro?". However it is no longer used and people now use the *da*-format (kiom da laboristoj).

Is it known **when, how and why this changed** and *"da"* became customary and (outside of poetry) seemingly even required?

Comment: Not much of an answer, but… There are a lot speakers, who for some reason have hard time to understand other grammatical cases than nominative. (Just see around in any _espa_ forum.)

Answer (score 1):

The article you linked, mentions that in *kiom laboristojn* you are using *kiom* as an adjective, but without ending. While it could be considered correct (mainly because Zamenhof said so), the fact is that it is not very coherent with the rest of the language (where you would expect the adjective to agree with the noun).

At the beginning of the language, as theory and practice met, there were structures that were tried/used but that did not go well with the rest of the language or showed the need for additional elements. An example: *kelk-* was used to mean *plur-* because *plur-* did not exist yet, after *plur-* appeared *kelk/* lost that original meaning (here in [PMEG](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/kvantaj_vortoj/e-vortoj.html)).

Another example: you can find things like *la multe da lupoj*. It's hard to say those are wrong, since they were used at the beginning by the initiators of the language, but they really feel weird. Today, in that special context you would probably say *la multo da lupoj* without much thinking (here in [PMEG](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/kvantaj_vortoj/e-vortoj.html)).

The language is alive, and that means users/speakers get to choose among competing forms, sometimes favouring the more coherent form. In this case, since we do use *kioma* as an adjective, it feels even more strange to use it as an adjective without any ending in just one context.

So all in all, to answer the question on when, why and how: pretty early; because it doesn't play well with the rest of the language; and through normal use as in all living languages.

Comment: It’s probably worth highlighting that *kioma* does not have the same meaning as the *kiom* in *kiom laboristojn*. Instead it is a question about the position in a sequence rather than about a quantity. Eg, *kioma horo estas?*.

Comment: @NeilRoberts _kioma_ car refer to both the quantity and the order. [vortaro.net](http://vortaro.net/#kioma).

Comment: @Eduaro Trápani, none of the examples in vortaro.net seem to back up that statement. PMEG has this comment: “Rimarku, ke kioma havas vicordan signifon same kiel nombraj vortetoj kun A-finaĵo (*unua*, *dua*...), dum la aliaj OM-vortoj (normale) ne havas tian vicordan signifon. Teorie oni povas uzi ankaŭ *kioma* en ne-vicorda senco, sed tiam oni riskas miskomprenon.”.

Comment: Interese. Tion vi celis per "vicorda"! Kiam mi legas "kioman fojon ..." mi _sentas_ kvanton kaj ripeton kiel ĉefajn trajtojn, ne vicordon. Sed mi komprenas, vi pravas. Nu, tio iel subtenas la respondon; jen alia nekoheraĵo en la uzo de _kiom_ en tiu frua Esperanto (la menciita en la demando).

Comment: To me, the fact that _"kioma"_ exists and the ordinal meaning it carries, both indicate that _"kiom"_ is not something adjective-like but rather something number-like, which should support the use without _"da"_ even without agreement to the noun. But of course, I can't argue with history, and this analogy goes only for _"kiom"_, not for all the _"...iom"_-words, and one would want those to be treated all the same.